# Variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times ...\times \mathbb{P}^{n_r}\times\mathbb{A}^{m} $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

I need help with defining variety in  $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times ...\times \mathbb{P}^{n_r}\times\mathbb{A}^{m} $.

I am reading Fulton's book, and in Chapter 6, this definition is used, but it is not made by the author. It is left as a task for the reader, and I can not do it.

I also accept an indication of a book where that definition is made.

THANK YOU.

Comment: A variety is the locus where a family of polynomials all vanish. Given the projective spaces, you will likely need to restrict to polynomials that are homogeneous in certain variables.

Comment: I believe it is not right what you say ... to do what you suggest is to define an irreducible algebraic set in $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times ...\times \mathbb{P}^{n_r}\times\mathbb{A}^{m} $. But this is not a variety in mixed spaces  $\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times ...\times \mathbb{P}^{n_r}\times\mathbb{A}^{m} $.